# Gateway not changing after restart

Tags: networking, network-interface, gateway

I'm using Ubuntu Server 14.04 and am trying to change the gateway.

I edited interfaces file in `/etc/network/interfaces` to include `gateway ip_here`, however when I type `ip route` it still shows the old gateway even after restarting the network/system.

For example, I type `ip route` and I get this:

```
10.1.10.208/28 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.10.210
10.1.32.0/26 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.32.15
```

I need the first ip to change to 213 (10.1.10.208 -> 10.1.10.213). How can I do this?